# How can I add text for each columns separatly?

Tags: python, treeview

I have a python treeview what used for a simple table and I do not know how can I add text for each columns separatly. I used .insert() to add text but how can I determine the place of it in table. Sorry If my english is not correct.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you are asking but if it's to take a variable and insert into specific column then you can do the following:

```
var_1 = "test"
var_2 = "test"
var_3 = "test"

# In this insert code, each var represents a different column
tree.insert('', 'end', values=(var_1, var_2, var_3))
```

Hope, this helps. Please provide your code so you can get better assistance.